# How do I get Confluence to render the result of a {sql-query} that contains wiki markup

Tags: sql, macros, wiki, confluence

I have the following in Confluence:

```
{panel}
Hello World 1
{panel}

{sql-query:datasource=DS|output=wiki|table=false|macros=true}
select '\{panel\}\\' from dual
{sql-query}

{sql-query:datasource=DS|output=wiki|table=false|macros=true}
select 'Hello World 2\\' from dual
{sql-query}

{sql-query:datasource=DS|output=wiki|table=false|macros=true}
select '\{panel\}' from dual
{sql-query}
```

The first panel (Hello World 1) displays correctly. The second panel (Hello World 2) does not. See output below.

[image: Confluence output]

How do I get Confluence to evaluate the wiki markup in the data that is returned from the SQL?

I have tried enclosing everything in a run macro e.g.

```
{run:hideParameters=true|hideRun=true|autoRun=true}
...
{run}
```

but this does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hair pulling, and thanks in part to the information provided in @Steffen's answer, I found the following solution:

```
{sql-query:datasource=DS|table=false|output=wiki}
select macroline from
(
    select 10 as seq, '{panel}' as macroline from dual
    union
    select 20 as seq, 'Hello World 2' as macroline from dual
    union
    select 30 as seq, '{panel}' as macroline from dual
)
order by seq
{sql-query}
```

A bit painful having to construct it all in one query but this gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this isn't supported by the [Confluence SQL Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/SQL/Confluence+SQL+Plugin) as envisioned:

A [Confluence Macro](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Working+with+Macros) is more or less a self contained unit (this is a bit simplified, but should illustrate the problem at hand). You are correctly asking the `{sql-query}` macro to evaluate other embodied macros by means of the `macros=true` parameter, which can only work for either 'single tag' macros (like e.g. the [Cheese Macro](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Cheese+Macro)) or *complete* 'double tag' macros though (i.e. macros that require embodied content in turn like the [Panel Macro](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Panel+Macro) you are trying to ínject).

Think of it this way: You are asking the `{sql-query]` macro to render a `{panel}`, which is missing its required closing tag, because all three `{sql-query]` macros work independently and don't communicate with each other to resolve macros. As usual, Confluence simply renders the macro tag as text therefore.

What you desire could be implemented in principle, but is likely out of scope regarding the use cases `{sql-query}` has been designed for currently.